# VBA excel get filenames from a folder

Tags: vba, get, filenames

From the below function I not able get the filenames to excel. Result variable is blank. Please help.

```
Dim Result As Variant

Function GetFileNames(ByVal FolderPath As String) As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim MyFile As Object
Dim MyFSO As Object
Dim MyFolder As Object
Dim MyFiles As Object
Set MyFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set MyFolder = MyFSO.GetFolder(FolderPath)
Set MyFiles = MyFolder.Files
ReDim Result(1 To MyFiles.Count)
i = 1
For Each MyFile In MyFiles
Result(i) = MyFile.Name
i = i + 1
Next MyFile
GetFileNames = Result
End Function

Sub GetFileNamesToExcel()
For Each MyFile In MyFiles
Result(i) = MyFile.Name
ActiveCell.Cells(i, 1).Value = Result(i)
i = i + 1
Next MyFile
End Sub
```

Thanks for your help.
Regards,
Balu.

Comment: You asked 5 questions, and none were marked as answered. please respect the repliers and if you get a valid answer, mark it as such.

Answer (score 0):

At first reading, I think your function is OK, but you use it badly.
I would use (quickly written - not tested, sorry)

```
Sub GetFileNamesToExcel()
    dim ar 
    ar = GetFileNames("d:\somefolder")
    'for results on a row
    range("a1").resize(1,ubound(ar))= ar  
    'for results in column (more probably what you want)
    range("a1").resize(ubound(ar),1) = application.transpose(ar)
End Sub
```

And you definitely don't need to use Result as a global variable. That's generally a bad practice, unless you have a specific reason to do that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and reminding to mark as answered.

Comment: Hi Patrick, For learning, If the Function GetFileNames(ByVal FolderPath As String) As Variant doesn't return anything, Function GetFileNames, How to retrieve the filenames from result variable. Thanks and Regards, Balu.